# zIndex and pagingEnabled property not working on React Native Android Build

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble with my android react-native app. I upgraded to 0.29.1 v to have some new features like, zIndex on Image component and pagingEnabled prop on Scroll View Component. I did a react-native upgrade , but these new features that where recently added to the 0.29 spec are not working on my android version (Working Properly  on iOS atm).

How do i make sure my my android app is running the latest version. My app.iml  also says its on react-native 0.29.1, and my package.json also indicates ^0.29.0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

zIndex was only added for iOS in 0.29

> Implement CSS z-index for iOS (d64368b) - @nicklockwood

In 0.30 it shows up again but this time not under a specific OS and the notes specify Android was tested. I would suspect that it should begin working on Android once 0.30 drops and you upgrade to that. As for pagingEnabled I don't see that in the release notes anywhere so I am not sure what is going on there.